# quiero insertar datos en una tabla relacionada de sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

hola tengo estas tablas creadas en SQL SERVER con el siguiente problema el cual no pude resolver por más vueltas que le dé. Aclaro soy un total novato en bases de datos.

```
create table sesion(
idSesion int not null Primary key identity(1,1),
horarioLog timestamp not null,
);
go

go
create table tipoUsuario(
idTipoUsuario int not null Primary key identity(1,1),
descripcion varchar (10) not null,
);
go

go
create table persona(
idPersona int not null Primary key identity(1,1),
nombre varchar(30) not null,
apellido varchar(20) not null,
email varchar(256) not null,
dni int not null,
);
go

go
create table usuario(
idUsuario int not null Primary key identity(1,1),
nombre varchar (20) not null,
contrasena varchar (256) not null,
idSesion int not null,
idTipoUsuario int not null,
idPersona int not null,
constraint FK_sesion_usuario foreign key(idSesion) references sesion(idSesion),
constraint FK_tipoUsuario_usuario foreign key(idTipoUsuario) references tipoUsuario(idTipoUsuario),
constraint FK_persona_usuario foreign key(idPersona) references persona(idPersona),
constraint UK_persona_usuario unique(idPersona),
);
go
```

quiero insertar registros y me sale este error. Me podrían decir ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

```
use pruebas;
INSERT INTO persona (nombre, apellido, email, dni) VALUES ('antonio','Perez','antonio@gmail.com', '37370935');
INSERT INTO tipoUsuario VALUES ('Secretario');
INSERT INTO sesion (horarioLog) VALUES (DEFAULT);
INSERT INTO usuario (nombre, contrasena) VALUES ('AniPz', 'afaushuf@3647');
```

Este es el error:
[image: Query]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Imagina que te responden con imágenes que tienes que transcribir. Bueno, pues eso, la idea es que los voluntarios acá puedan usar y replicar tu código y tu problema. Copia y pega todo esto como texto y ve a [edit] para ajustar tu pregunta

Comment: te faltan campos que ingresar en la tabla usuarios.. como esperas que sepa cuales son los id relacionados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basado en tu propio comentario de que eres novato y en los comentarios, veo que tienes los 3 primeros `INSERT` correctamente, sin embargo, supongo que el último no sabes como insertarlo.

Para poder hacerlo tienes que llamar a todas a las columnas que faltan y que haz declarado en tus primeros scripts de `CREATE`, es decir los siguientes campos:

- <kbd>idSesion</kbd>
- <kbd>idTipoUsuario</kbd>
- <kbd>idPersona</kbd>

Por tanto la consulta (en principio) queda así:

```sql
insert into usuario(nombre,contrasena, idSesion, idTipoUsuario, idPersona)
```

Luego, supongo, piensas que se agregarán las id's automáticamente o algo por el estilo y no es así, hay mil formas de hacerlo, pero si no quieres complicarte puedes usar `IDENT_CURRENT`, seleccionar la tabla y hacer referencia al último ID insertado en esa tabla.

La consulta final quedaría así:

```sql
insert into persona
            (nombre,
             apellido,
             email,
             dni)
values      ( 'antonio',
              'Perez',
              'antonio@gmail.com',
              '37370935' );

insert into tipousuario
values      ('Secretario');

insert into sesion
            (horariolog)
values      (default);

insert into usuario
            (nombre,
             contrasena,
             idsesion,
             idtipousuario,
             idpersona)
values      ( 'AniPz',
              'afaushuf@3647',
              ident_current('persona'),
              ident_current('tipoUsuario'),
              ident_current('sesion') )
```

```sql
4 rows affected
```

Comment: Hay que tener cuidado al usar ident_current porque puede traer un valor incorrecto si alguien más insertó un valor en alguna de las tablas antes de que se ejecute el insert a usuario. Sería mejor usar `SCOPE_IDENTITY`

Comment: Mmm claro, pero en ese caso SCOPE_IDENTITY devolverá de la última ID generada por cualquier tabla, para este caso en particular se requieren de las últimas ID de 3 tablas en el mismo tiempo.

Comment: Para eso se pueden asignar los valores a distintas variables.